# Is there a maximum number of Google Cloud IoT MQTT device configuration submissions allowed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

I would like to know if there is an absolute maximum number of device configurations that can be sent per device through MQTT on Google Cloud? I know configurations are rate limited to 1/sec and the most recent 10 are "cached", but I need to know if eventually, we could hit a max number, ie: v100000.

I could not find info about a max limit on: https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas

Comment: I have found Google's quota pages to be encompassing.  IT seems that you are rate limited but not constrained on totals over time.  If we had been, I would have expected to see an entry in the quotas table.

Comment: Seems that this is a hard limit and even though is not mentioned the max number of device configurations submissions allowed, its mentioned that : "Configuration updates are limited to 1 update per second, per device. However, for best results, device configuration should be updated much less often — at most, once every 10 seconds.". So, a large number of configurations submitted could affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The comments covering the maximum limits of device configurations are correct. There is not a limit to how many configuration updates you can perform but only the last 10 updates will persist in the update history and you're rate limited to [the quotas listed in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iot/quotas).

Just out of curiosity why are you having a concern around the limits of how many configurations can be sent?